# GCE VM Instance disappeared from Cloud Console after reboot it from a SSH session

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was connected to a VM instance (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) over a SSH session to do routine maintenance activities.

After a "reboot" command, the instance simply disappeared from my account. The boot disk is missing as well. I have an old snapshot, but there's no other trace of that instance anywhere. Or its external reserved IP.

I'm at a complete loss as to what may have happened. I did not take any other actions on my account or sent any other commands. There's nothing in the console either. It's as if the VM has never existed...?

What could I check in order to find out what happened with the VM and recover it?

Comment: The first step is to figure out how the instance was removed. That detail is recorded in the Google Cloud Audit logs. If you find nothing in the logs, then must engage Google Cloud Support. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit

Comment: Have you solved your issue?